# display current logged username

Tags: php, sql

im trying to display the username of the current logged user

the table looks like this: Table Name: system_users   , u_userid - gets the id u_username - gets the user name

i want to display the u_username... it works at the momment but it display all users.

this is the code, it display all users, i want to display only the logged user

```
<?php 
 $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'SQLUSER', 'SQLPW'); //The Blank 
 string is the password
 mysql_select_db('comenzi.highmob');

 $query = "SELECT * FROM system_users"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
 $result = mysql_query($query);

 echo "<table>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through 
 results
 echo "<tr><td>" . $row['u_username'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index 
 here is a field name
 }

  echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

 mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
     ?>
```

Comment: [**Please don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](//stackoverflow.com/q/12859942)! They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](//wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](//php.net/manual/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](//php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](//php.net/mysqli) - [this article](//php.net/manual/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) can help you choose. If you go with PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Where's the session information? How are you managing the session?

Comment: require_once("config.php");
     if (!isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) || $_SESSION["user_id"] == "") {
         // not logged in send to login page
         redirect("index.php");
      $_SESSION['id']=$current_user_id;
      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use where condition

For Example

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM system_users WHERE UserID = 2"
```

in your case you can get the userid from the session

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the MySQL user:

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER();
```

If you're referring to the logged in user for your application, it depends on the application. Are you modifying an existing application you can provide a link to?

You probably want something like

```
SELECT * FROM system_users WHERE u_userid = (your user id here)
```

Comment: in this case everything works fine but if i write u_userid = 1 it means that all the time will display the u_userid 1 wich is the admin. it will display all the time that admin is connected.